# Stripe elements not sending token with form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

My token isnt sent with the rest of the form. Would like it all to be sent as one form. As of know it only displays when I execute the form. Don't know much js and would greatly appreciate any help

```
// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {
  hidePostalCode: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#666EE8',
      color: '#31325F',
      lineHeight: '40px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7E0',
      },
    },
  }
});
card.mount('#card-element');

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');

    // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    //form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var options = {
    address_line1: document.getElementById('address-line1').value,
    address_city: document.getElementById('address-city').value,
    address_zip: document.getElementById('address-zip').value,
  };

  stripe.createToken(card, options).then(setOutcome);
});
```

This is copied straight from https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/dheyftzp/ with some minor changes to fit me and a standard form also copied from the link above

```
  <form action="/pay/" method="POST">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" />
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Card</span>
        <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Address</span>
        <input id="address-line1" name="address_line1" class="field" placeholder="77 Winchester Lane" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Stad</span>
        <input id="address-city" name="address_city" class="field" placeholder="Coachella" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Postnummer</span>
        <input id="address-zip" name="address_zip" class="field" placeholder="92236" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Betala</button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error"></div>
      <div class="success">
        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: please make sure stripe key is set correctly, and also look for js error in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother actually found the answer, one of the lines that appended the token to the form were unchecked.

```
form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
```